# How to change Encoding in PDF after converting SVG to PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, encoding, itext, itext7

I've created a converter API which is converting SVG files into PDF. Application using iText v8.0.1. My SVG file have encoding= utf-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

PDF Document Properties after conversion looks like this:

[image: PDF DOC]

Why the Font used in this document is default: Helvetica and why Encoding Type is set to Ansi, even if i got this all information in SVG file? For example font in SVG file:

```
text.F0{fill: rgb(0,0,0); font-size: 2.2356px; text-anchor: start; dominant-baseline: alphabetic; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana}
```

I don't know if it is a problem with Encoding or Fonts. But if i changed font to different one, it doesn't help...
Im trying to resolve the issue with overlaping elements in PDF file after convertion.

How it should be:
[image: 1]

How it acctual is:
[image: 2]

***UPDATE***

**Added class for change font-size from px to pt:**

```
public class FontConverter
{
    public static string ConvertFontSizesFromPxToPt(string svgContent)
    {
        float pxToPtConversionFactor = 1.3333f;

        XmlDocument svgDocument = new XmlDocument();
        svgDocument.LoadXml(svgContent);

        XmlNodeList textElements = svgDocument.SelectNodes("//text");
        foreach (XmlNode textElement in textElements)
        {
            if (textElement.Attributes["font-size"] != null)
            {
                string fontSizePx = textElement.Attributes["font-size"].Value;
                float fontSizePt = float.Parse(fontSizePx.Replace("px", "")) * pxToPtConversionFactor;
                textElement.Attributes["font-size"].Value = $"{fontSizePt}pt";
            }
        }
        return svgDocument.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

**Im using this class here:**

```
public class SettingPdfPage
{
    public static void SettingUpPdfPage(PdfDocument doc, string pageSvgContent)
    {
        var pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();
        doc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
        doc.AddNewPage();

        var canvas = new PdfCanvas(doc.GetLastPage());

        // Scale transformation
        float scaleX = .704f; // Adjust as needed
        float scaleY = .704f; // Adjust as needed

        Rectangle pageRectangle = doc.GetLastPage().GetPageSize();
        float svgWidth = pageRectangle.GetWidth() * scaleX;
        float svgHeight = pageRectangle.GetHeight() * scaleY;
        float translateX = (pageRectangle.GetWidth() - svgWidth) / 99;
        float translateY = (pageRectangle.GetHeight() - svgHeight) / 90;

        // Apply the scaling transformation to the canvas
        canvas.ConcatMatrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, translateX, translateY);

        var svgContent = FontConverter.ConvertFontSizesFromPxToPt(pageSvgContent);

        SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(svgContent, doc, 1);
    }
}
```

**But it didn't help me**

Comment: The problem of overlapping text elements is unrelated to text encodings. Also, please don't post pictures/screenshots of code. Put code as text formatted as "code block" into your question. Bonus points for making your code screenshot low-contrast (bonus points you would miss if you were to put the code as "code-block"-formatted text into your question).

Comment: Soo it seems iText v8.0.1 is bugged or what? I tried many many things to resolve that problem but nothing helped me. @KJ

Comment: I upload some changes to convert text-size from px to pt. Can you analyze what's wrong with that isnt working? @KJ

Comment: Can you provide a short, self-contained example to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: @mkl, yea i will try do simple console app which will generate PDF from SVG

Comment: *"i will try do simple console app which will generate PDF from SVG"* - and an SVG file for which the app outputs the erroneous result...

Comment: PDF is a file containing PostScript print instructions, not a document. Those instructions *do* include vector operations, moving to specific coordinates in a page, typing text with specific fonts, drawing etc. The images you posted show footers, not graphics. It seems like you tried to *print* a document in one vector format and now you're trying to convert it to another.

Comment: Why are you trying to go through SVG instead of directly to PostScript? What you show isn't an encoding issue at all - if anything, the text is all English. The problem is using the wrong coordinates. All the text seems to be centered on the same coordinates The sizes are also unexpected. `px` means `Pixel` and `font-size: 2.2356px` means you want to use *just two black dots*.

Comment: @mkl Here you are: https://github.com/TomaszFlorczyk/iText-fixing.git